# multiple image in array in input field custom form in magento 2.4

Tags: image, post-data, magento2.4.0

Now i am using input field file[] array so how to $filesData = $this->getRequest()->getFiles('files'); use foreach loop

```
<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" title="" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}">
```

> Post.php

```
    public function execute()
    {

    $filesData = $this->getRequest()->getFiles('files');

    **echo "<pre>";
    print_r($filesData);
    echo "</pre>";
    exit;**

    if ($filesData['name']) {
        $uploader = $this->fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'files']);
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
        $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['txt', 'csv', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'pdf', 'doc', 'docx']);
        $path = $this->fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('test-doc');
        $result = $uploader->save($path);
        $upload_document = 'test-doc'.$uploader->getUploadedFilename();
        $filePath = $result['path'].$result['file'];
        $fileName = $result['name'];
    } else {
        $upload_document = '';
        $filePath = '';
        $fileName = '';
    }
```

}

Comment: Please check and update me.

Comment: Please check my question @Msquare

Comment: you have got $filesData array  simple use for loop for upload image. Please check my For Save Image code ad update me.

Answer (score 0):

> **phtml form be like this**

```
<form class="form"
      name="inquiryFrom"
      action="productinquiry/productinquiry/save"
      id="inq-form"
      method="post"
      enctype='multipart/form-data'
      autocomplete="off"
      >
      <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <div id="file-upload-section" class="field file">
          <label class="label" for="inquiry_msg">
            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml('Upload File:') ?></span>
          </label>
          <div class="control">
            <input id="attachment-file"
                   class="attachment-file"
                   name="attachment[]"
                   type="file"
                   multiple="multiple" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
          <button type="submit"
                  id="inq-submit"
                  class="action submit primary "
                  title="<?= $block->escapeHtml('Submit') ?>" >
              <span><?= $block->escapeHtml('Submit') ?></span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

> **For Save Image**

```
protected $fileSystem;

protected $uploaderFactory;


public function __construct(
    .............................................
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $fileSystem,
    \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
    .............................................
) {
    .............................................
    $this->fileSystem = $fileSystem;
    $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
    .............................................
}

public function execute()
{
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

    // attechmengt save
    $filesData = $this->getRequest()->getFiles('attachment');
    $length = count($filesData);
    $file_store = '';
    try {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            if ($filesData[$i]['error'] == 0) {
                $field_name = "attachment[" . $i . "]";
                $uploaderFactory = $this->uploaderFactory->create(["fileId" => $field_name]);
                $uploaderFactory->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
                $uploaderFactory->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                $uploaderFactory->setFilesDispersion(true);
                $mediaDirectory = $this->fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
                $destinationPath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('tmp/attachment');
                $result = $uploaderFactory->save($destinationPath);
                if (!$result) {
                    throw new LocalizedException(
                        __('File cannot be saved to path: $1', $destinationPath)
                    );
                }
                $file_store .= $result['file'] . ",";
            }
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addError(__('Attachment not Uplaoded, Please try Agrain'));
    }
    $data['attachment'] = $file_store;

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data)
    exit();

    .....................................
    .....................................
}
```